# get/set package user-dir before installing org-mode

Tags: org-mode, package

I have emacs 24.5.1 on Xubuntu 14.04. I want to install the latest version of the `org` package available in GNU ELPA (20150929). Following the [advice](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html#Installation) on org-mode website, I launch emacs with the `-q` option: `$ emacs -q`. Then, I do `M-x list-packages` and install `org`. By default, it ends up being installed in `~/.emacs.d/elpa`.

However, in my `~/.emacs`, I have `(setq package-user-dir "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")`. Therefore, with `emacs -q`, how can I change the value of this variable?

Comment: You should be able to simply evaluate that same `setq` after starting `emacs -q`, before installing. Or from the command line: `emacs -q --eval '(setq ...)'`. Or very likely just install to the default directory and then manually copy the directory to where you want it to be?

Comment: You can do `M-: (setq package-user-dir "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")` before `M-x list-package`

Comment: You do not need to install packages in an `emacs -q` session. Those instructions are there so that a user gets a consistent way to install `org-mode` if something in their config is causing problem with that. If you can install org-mode fine in your regular emacs session, you do not need to do it in `emacs -q`.